# Adding viewcontrollers in scrollview ios swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, xcode8

I am having baseview controller with scrollview.In that scrollview I adding three viewcontrollers view(xib).So i can scroll those three in horizantal.In my first view controller I am displaying a tablevieew.While running my app,Its displaying all my 3 view controllers.But When I touch my tableview cell are disappeared.Same I have did in xcode 7.3.It was working fine.But in xcode 8 its not working.Please help me to solve this.I have attached my sample code

```
let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollContainer.frame.width
        let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.scrollContainer.frame.height
        let x = CGFloat(i) * scrollViewWidth

        if i == 0{
            let qualification = EducationViewController (nibName: "EducationViewController", bundle: nil)
            //qualification.view.frame.size.height = scrollViewHeight
            //qualification.view.frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth
            qualification.view.frame.origin.x = x
            self.scrollContainer!.addSubview(qualification.view)
            qualification.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
        else if i == 1{
            let state = StateRegistrationViewController (nibName: "StateRegistrationViewController", bundle: nil)
            //state.view.frame.size.height = scrollViewHeight
           // state.view.frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth
            state.view.frame.origin.x = x
            self.scrollContainer!.addSubview(state.view)
            state.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            state.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
        else if i == 2{
            let exp = ExperienceViewController (nibName: "ExperienceViewController", bundle: nil)
           // exp.view.frame.size.height = scrollViewHeight
           // exp.view.frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth
            exp.view.frame.origin.x = x
            self.scrollContainer!.addSubview(exp.view)
            exp.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

            exp.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Initiate the viewController

   ```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let aViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A") as! AViewController;
   let bViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B") as! BViewController;
   let cViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "C") as! CViewController;
   ```
2. Add the viewControllers into an array

   ```
   let viewControllers = [aViewController, bViewController, cViewController]
   ```
3. Run the for loop which adds the viewControllers to the scrollView

   ```
   var idx:Int = 0
   for viewController in viewControllers {

       addChildViewController(viewController);
       let originX:CGFloat = CGFloat(idx) * width;
       viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: 0, width: width, height: height);
       scrollView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
       viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
       idx += 1;
   }
   ```

All Done!

Answer (score 0):

while adding the view of your custom viewcontroller on scrollview you should also add your custom viewcontroller as child controller of the main controller.

like in your case you have three custom controllers then as per the if else clause in your code you must add:

```
self.addChildViewController(qualification)
self.addChildViewController(state)
self.addChildViewController(exp)
```

in there respective blocks in your code.

Your code will be like:

```
let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollContainer.frame.width
        let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.scrollContainer.frame.height
        let x = CGFloat(i) * scrollViewWidth

        if i == 0{
            let qualification = EducationViewController (nibName: "EducationViewController", bundle: nil)
            //qualification.view.frame.size.height = scrollViewHeight
            //qualification.view.frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth
            qualification.view.frame.origin.x = x
            self.scrollContainer!.addSubview(qualification.view)
            self.addChildViewController(qualification)
            qualification.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
        else if i == 1{
            let state = StateRegistrationViewController (nibName: "StateRegistrationViewController", bundle: nil)
            //state.view.frame.size.height = scrollViewHeight
           // state.view.frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth
            state.view.frame.origin.x = x
            self.scrollContainer!.addSubview(state.view)
            self.addChildViewController(state)
            state.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            state.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
        else if i == 2{
            let exp = ExperienceViewController (nibName: "ExperienceViewController", bundle: nil)
           // exp.view.frame.size.height = scrollViewHeight
           // exp.view.frame.size.width = scrollViewWidth
            exp.view.frame.origin.x = x
            self.scrollContainer!.addSubview(exp.view)
            self.addChildViewController(exp)
            exp.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

            exp.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }}
```